# Как понять, как произносится буква "C" в начале слова?

Tags: фонетика

Возьмём два слова – "свалка" и "сделал".
У слова "сделал" первая **c** произносится как [з], а у слова "свалка" произносится как [с].
Есть ли какое-то правило о том, как произносится первая **с** в слове?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В русской графике принято, что для обозначения звука [с] используется две буквы: буква "з" и буква "с". Есть и обратная ситуация, когда для обозначения звука [з] используются те же самые буквы.

---

Тогда как, спрашивается, их различить? Все дело в позиции той или иной буквы в слове (важно понимать, какие буквы окружают нашу и какие звуки эти самые буквы под собой скрывают: гласные, согласные, какие согласные: глухие, твердые и т.д. Немаловажную роль играют в этом всем фонетические законы)
Посмотрите на примеры:

1. -замазка [замаска]
2. -нос [нос]
3. -сдоба [здоба]
4. -зал [зал]

На примерах 1 и 3 можно наблюдать действие двух фонетических законов русского языка: оглушения и озвончения.

---

1)При оглушении последующий глухой согласный звук оглушает предыдущий (в слове "замазка" глухой согласный "к" повлияет на "з" и превратил его в звук [с])
2)При озвончении последующий звонкий согласный звук озвончает предыдущий (в слове "сдоба" звонкий согласный "д" повлиял на "с" и превратил его в звук [з])
Дело в том, что "з/с" - это те согласные, которые имеют пару по глухости/звонкости, которые сами стоят перед парными согласными, поэтому в таких словах действуют фонетические законы озвончения и оглушения.

---

***Что касается вашего примера:***
В слове "свалка" звук "с" стоит перед согласным, который, хоть и считается парным (его пара - "ф"), никак не изменяет характер предшествующего звука, поэтому закон **озвончения** тут не работает.
А вот в слове "сделал" уже все идет по правилам: глухой согласный (парный) "с", который стоит перед звонким согласным (парным) "д", **озвончается**, превращаясь в свою звонку пару - звук [з].

Comment: А почему в слове "Свалка" не работает закон озвончения, это исключение или здесь работает какой-то другой закон?

Comment: Нет. Само слово "свалка" не исключение. Дело в том, что перед сонорными согласными, гласными и перед "в/в'" не может происходить ни озвончения, ни оглушения, поэтому в таких словах все произносится без экзотики.